# '4.6.0-preview6.19303.8' is not a valid version string. Unable to Install Nuget Packages in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

Usually I work on .NET 4.5, My colleague had .NET 4.6.2 installed on his machine, gave me Project for me to do changes.

In Nuget Console, following below error is displayed
  '4.6.0-preview6.19303.8' is not a valid version string.

I am trying hard to Update Nuget Packages it shows me below error, what does it mean..

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 4.1.0
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Owin (≥ 1.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin (≥ 4.1.0)'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Owin 4.1.0'.
You are downloading Microsoft.Owin from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/v4.0.1/LICENSE.txt. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin 4.1.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 4.1.0'.
You are downloading Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/v4.0.1/LICENSE.txt. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 4.1.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : '4.6.0-preview6.19303.8' is not a valid version string.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 4.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

After Nuget Update, Got to know Nuget is up to date

```
PM> nuget update -self
Checking for updates from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/nuget.commandline/index.json
Currently running NuGet.exe 5.5.1.
NuGet.exe is up to date.
Update successful.
```

Comment: Can you try running `nuget help` in the Package Manager Console of VS and see which version of nuget you're using? It could be because older version of nuget does not support pre-release numbers with dot notation (as in `4.6.0-preview6.19303.8`).

Comment: If the nuget version is < to 4.3.0, use `nuget update -self` in the console and try again.

Comment: Let me try once. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's related to nuget version, as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning):

> NuGet 4.3.0+ supports SemVer 2.0.0, which supports pre-release numbers with dot notation, as in 1.0.1-build.23. Dot notation is not supported with NuGet versions before 4.3.0. You can use a form like 1.0.1-build23.

In your case, `4.6.0-preview6.19303.8` is a "pre-release numbers with dot notation" (the '.' between "preview6" and "19303").

You can check the nuget version you're using by typing `nuget help` in the Package Manager Console of Visual Studio, then update it with `nuget update -self`

Additionally, it appears that there is also limitation on the version of Visual Studio:

> Certain semantics of SemVer v2.0.0 are not supported in older clients. NuGet considers a package version to be SemVer v2.0.0 specific if either of the following statements is true:
>
> - **The pre-release label is dot-separated, for example, 1.0.0-alpha.1**

and

> If you upload a SemVer v2.0.0-specific package to nuget.org, the package is invisible to older clients and available to only the following NuGet clients:
>
> - NuGet 4.3.0+
> - **Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3+**
> - **Visual Studio 2015 with NuGet VSIX v3.6.0**
> - dotnet
>         dotnetcore.exe (.NET SDK 2.0.0+)

Comment: Hi colinD, I have updated Nuget, its already Up to Date. Please check question I have pasted Code.

Comment: Apparently you also need VS 2015 or more, see my edit.

Comment: Hi colinD,  Thanks for suggestion, Have a query, the error message says 4.6.0, does it have something to do with .NET version

Comment: I can't be sure of that. The problem seems to come from the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package, but I can't tell more from the log.

Comment: Ok colinD will try installing newer version of Visual studio, then will try again installing packages. Thanks

Comment: Thanks colinD, it worked, Upgraded to Visual Studio 19